# About the "There is already a source with this ID" that appears in mapbox

Tags: javascript, php, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to save multiple latitude and longitude information retrieved from the database into a single Symbol Layer using a for statement.
However, I get the error "There is already a source with this ID".
I don't know how to solve this problem. Please let me know how to solve this.

Here is the source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>マップを表示</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.6.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.6.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var lat=[38.943951,38.909664,38.914581];
    var log=-[-77.052477,-77.043444,-77.031706];

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'myid';
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', 
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', 
        center: [136.447164, 35.483184],
        zoom: 9 // starting zoom
        });
        map.on('load', () => {
            for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
                map.addSource('places', {
                // This GeoJSON contains features that include an "icon"
                // property. The value of the "icon" property corresponds
                // to an image in the Mapbox Streets style's sprite.
                    'type': 'geojson',
                    'data': {
                        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                        'features': [
                        {
                            'type': 'Feature',
                            'properties': {
                            'description':
                                '<p>テスト</p>',
                                'icon': 'theatre-15'
                        },
                        'geometry': {
                            'type': 'Point',
                            'coordinates': [log[i], lat[i]]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    });
            }

        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'places',
            'type': 'symbol',
            'source': 'places',
            'layout': {
            'icon-image': '{icon}',
            'icon-allow-overlap': true
        }
        });
    });
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```js
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
                map.addSource('places', {
```

You're adding a source inside a loop. So you're adding the source multiple times. Hence the error message.

You need to use the loop to create the GeoJSON object, then add it just once.